# Making a HTML table based on SQL data in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I am trying to make a dynamic HTML table with PHP, populating it with data from MySQL database. So far I have tried the while loop, but the result ends up in displaying the same first row it gets multiple times.

```
<div class = "container">
        <p>Registered companies:</p>
        <table border = "1px" align = "left">
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Company name</th>
                <th>Company value1</th>
                <th>Company value2</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $compRowIncrement = 0;
                while ($compRowIncrement < $companyRowCount) {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $companyRow['user_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $companyRow['company_name']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $companyRow['company_value1']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $companyRow['company_value2']?></td>
                    </tr>
            <?php
                    $compRowIncrement++;
                }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

It should display 3 rows of data for example (SQL query returns 3 different values). But so far I have achieved to get 3 rows (like I need) with the same data (first value it gets from the database).

How do I do it so each table row is populated with different data, as it is in the database.

I'm just learning, so if you don't mind ignore the css values in table :).

EDIT1 (Added query)//

```
$getPlayerCompanies = $MySQLi_CON -> query("SELECT DISTINCT *
                                              FROM companies
                                              LEFT JOIN player ON companies.player_id = player.player_id
                                              LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = player.user_id
                                              WHERE users.user_id =".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$companyRow = $getPlayerCompanies -> fetch_array();
$companyRowCount = $getPlayerCompanies -> num_rows;
```

Following query currently returns 3 rows, like it should.

Comment: show the $companyRow statement from the server

Comment: If this is a SQL query you should limit the return to return the number of records you want. Also won't need `while ($compRowIncrement < $companyRowCount) {` just loop the `fetch`.

Comment: Added SQL query. Query is already limited to be logged on user based. Also without the increment, the while loop loops to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where did the $companyRow values get populated?

I belive your code should be more like this (or with mysqli commands)

```
<?php
     while ($companyRow = $getPlayerCompanies -> fetch_array() ) 
     {
?>
         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $companyRow['user_name']?></td>
             ...
         </tr>
<?php 
     }
?>
```

Comment: Added the query to original question.

Comment: Maybe it's my query, but this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: thank you for showing your query and the name of your result set. I have edited my code to include your $getPlayerCompanies result set

you don't need to use increment counters, just a while loop on fetch_array(). When the results run out of arrays to fetch, it will exit the while loop.

Comment: I also had to delete the $companyRow = $getPlayerCompanies -> fetch_array(); row under the original query, otherwise it skips the first row and returns only 2 next rows. But this worked well, thanks alot :)